# Unwanted termination of python code from M1 Macbook

Tags: python, apple-m1, termination

When I run a heavy code with very large sized array from my M1 Macbook in IDLE, it terminates with `===RESTART: Shell===` message, and terminates also from terminal with message of `zsh: killed`, although it runs well when I reduce the number of length of dimensions of the array, both in IDLE and terminal.

For example, for the code from the oldest answer of a posting at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/274360/255121, it runs well when `N=60`, but the unwanted termination occurs when it is increased to `N=200`. Is it a problem of M1 Macbook?

Comment: Does it work on some other machine? It sounds like you are just running out of memory.

Comment: It didn't work from a window laptop either

Comment: Memory isn't infinite.  If you want to run a very large calculation that requires a lot of space, you need to store some of that data on disk.

Comment: Well, `200**4` is one hundred times bigger than `60**4`. You are just running out of memory. There's not much you can do beyond buying more memory or heavily rewriting your code to work off disk. (And increasing your memory 100x is probably not feasible, even if it is possible.)